# How to convert from char* to id* with ARC enabled

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I'm trying to construct "fake" variable arguments list, using the technique described [here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/05/variable-argument-lists-in-cocoa.html), but for ARC-enabled project and I can't figure out how to get rid of the error I'm getting.

Here's the code in question:

```
NSMutableArray* argumentsArray = [NSMutableArray array];

// ... Here I fill argumentsArray with some elements
// And then, I want to construct a "fake" variable argument list

char* fakeArgList = (char*) malloc( sizeof(NSString*) * [argumentsArray count]); 
[argumentsArray getObjects: (id*) fakeArgList];

NSString* content = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: formatString arguments:fakeArgList];
```

XCode complains on the *(id*) fakeArgList* casting, saying:

> Cast of non-Objective-C pointer type 'char *' to '_autoreleasing id *'
>   is disallowed with ARC

My initial theory was that I just need to add __unsafe_unretained to (id*) casting to tell ARC that I'm responsible for that block of memory and it shouldn't retain/release it, but that doesn't work and I can't figure out how to fix this problem.

**Update:** Here's the full function. It should take a printf-style format string and a variable list of field names inside the .plist and output a formatted string with data loaded from .plist. I.e., if I have a .plist file with fields "field1" = "foo" and "field2" = 3 and I call `[loadStringFromFixture: @"?param1=%@&param2=%d", @"field1", @field2]`  then I should get string "?param1=foo&param2=3"

```
- (NSString*) loadStringFromFixture:(NSString*) format, ...
{
    NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSString* finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MockAPI-Fixtures.plist"];
    NSDictionary* plistData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:finalPath];

    va_list argumentsList;    
    va_start(argumentsList, format);

    NSString* nextArgument;
    NSMutableArray* argumentsArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    while((nextArgument = va_arg(argumentsList, NSString*)))
    {
        [argumentsArray addObject: [plistData objectForKey:nextArgument]];
    }

    NSRange myRange = NSMakeRange(0, [argumentsArray count]);

    id* fakeArgList = (__bridge id *)malloc(sizeof(NSString *) * [argumentsArray count]); 
    [argumentsArray getObjects:fakeArgList range:myRange];
    NSString * content = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:formatString
                                                arguments:(__bridge va_list)fakeArgList];

    free(fakeArgList);

    return content;
}
```

Comment: There must be a better way to do this...

Comment: Seriously;   a quick read of the source article leaves me thinking that it only works by coincidence and is outside the bounds of the ABI or spec.

Comment: That's true, but I need it only for my unit-test code, so I'm less concerned with the fact that it's a pretty "dirty hack". Though if someone can point out to a better way to construct a variable arguments list, I'm really interested.

Comment: Try something like `__builtin_va_arg_pack` documented in [Constructing Calls](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Constructing-Calls.html), maybe? ARC restricts object pointers to be either valid or `nil` at all times.

Comment: More generally: You should ask a question about what you are trying to do and how it might be done. This is one approach, but another might avoid needing to do it at all.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at this code, it seems like a pretty dirty hack, but I suppose if it worked without ARC, it should also work *with* ARC. The problem here is that you're casting from C-pointers to Objective-C pointers, which you cannot do without bridging:

```
NSMutableArray * argumentsArray = [NSMutableArray array];

// ... Here I fill argumentsArray with some elements
// And then, I want to construct a "fake" variable argument list

NSRange myRange = NSMakeRange(0, [argumentsArray count]);
id * fakeArgList = (__bridge id *)malloc(sizeof(NSString *) * [argumentsArray count]); 
[argumentsArray getObjects:fakeArgList range:myRange];
NSString * content = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:formatString
                                            arguments:(__bridge va_list)fakeArgList];
free(fakeArgList);
```

This is still pretty ugly, and I really hope that there is a better way of doing this, but since it is for a unit test, I guess it will have to do.

**EDIT**: It may be that the bridged cast should be done like this instead:

```
id __autoreleasing * fakeArgList = (__bridge id __autoreleasing *)malloc(sizeof(NSString *) * [argumentsArray count]);
```

Comment: Still got compiler errors with that code. It complains about "Incompatible types casting "void *" to "__autoreleasing id *" with a __bridge cast" on the line with malloc.

Comment: My edit may be your solution, or it may be totally off. Check it out and see.